# Area 51 Upvote Dialog Preventing Upvotes from Piling on One Question

Tags: feature-request, area-51

When adding a question to a proposal, you only need ten upvotes to have it count towards the proposal. The thing is, new followers waste their five votes on the most popular questions that already count towards the proposal.

Shouldn't there be a *This post only needs 10 upvotes to count towards the proposal* dialog or limit? The dialog could fall in the same one as the *You have only [number] of votes left on this proposal*. See LGBT+ on Area 51 for an example.

Comment: For someone who wants to support a question it is a good thing to know if that 10 is all you need and this causes the person to create their own good/bad questions and to vote or not vote on questions that are under 10.  The choice is still theirs.

Comment: I've seen other stack exchange users put it in the comment section of their proposal and in conversations about the proposal. People don't know that all you need is 10 to begin with because the're never made aware of it.  I was the same to begin with.

Comment: @Jody This is a good thing.  Proposals that barely hit the minimum requirements, and only due to vote cherry picking, is a pretty strong indicator that it won't pass muster.  Better to have a strong enough following to easily meet the requirements organically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who wants to support a question, it is a good thing to know if that 10 is all you need and this causes the person to create their own good/bad questions and to vote or not vote on questions that are under 10. The choice is still theirs.

I've seen other Stack Exchange users put it in the comment section of their proposal and in conversations about the proposal. People don't know that all you need is 10 to begin with because the're never made aware of it. I was the same to begin with.

Answer (score 12):

I disagree. The votes are a metric whether there are enough good quality questions. If there are only a few good posts, and people tend only to vote on those, maybe the proposal isn't that strong.

If there are enough people joining, they will have other likes and dislikes so they will vote differently. The "you only have 10 votes" dialog says enough. We don't want people to vote on bad questions, just to get a proposal through.

Comment: But is that because of the quality, or the limit of votes? Maybe the ordering of the questions should be randomized to get a fair amount of views. It seems a proposal should have more followers too, so they will equal the difference out. Not all of them vote on the first 10.

Answer (score 3):

So whenever someone doesn't like a popular question they get to remove it from the acceptable questions with their *one single vote*? You **really** don't want this; you want good questions to have solid vote totals, not just the absolute minimum, otherwise you give dissenting votes a disproportional amount of influence.

Let people vote as they see fit, those that grasp what building a community and body of questions will know how to most effectively vote.

top focusing on getting to the required number of questions as fast as you can, and instead focus on building actually good questions and a community that can stand behind them.